# How to run web server (Warp) in async/concurrent mode?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, haskell-wai, haskell-warp

I'm using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.24/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html

I don't know much about haskell concurrency. Say I would like to run two servers on different ports:

So I do:

```hs
 do
   Warp.run 3000 waiApp
   Warp.run 3002 waiApp
```

Then server is run on 3000 is working, but it never gets to the next line.

I tried:

```hs
 do
   forkIO $ Warp.run 3000 waiApp
   forkIO $ Warp.run 3002 waiApp
```

But it doesn't seem to work, each of them just stop after forking.

How to make it work properly? Also I want to allow the code below to be executed aslo.

UPD:

So the current solution is just to add

```
forever (threadDelay 1000)
```

in the end of the `main`, I wonder if it is the correct way to do this.

Comment: In your last example: just remove the second forkIO, so that your main thread doesn't terminate right away, but is busy running the second server.

Comment: Ah, thanks, and if I want to keep the second forkIO and let the code below execute, what better way to just make the main thread run forever?

Comment: The best way is to give it something to do like running a server, or checking that all server threads still run... Everything else is just a waste of the threads resources.

Comment: @cafce25 You mean say `forever (threadDelay $ 1000 * 1000)` is not a good solution?

Comment: Doing useless computation forever does not seem very good no.

Comment: Ok, I made with `Async.wait`, probably, it is correct solution for my case.

Answer (score 2):

So, we should not allow the main thread to terminate. Something like this should work:

```hs
 do
   a1 <- Async.async $ Warp.run 3000 waiApp
   a2 - Async.async $ Warp.run 3002 waiApp
   ...
   Async.waitAny [a1, a2]
```